# Coxcomb chart in qgis

Tags: qgis, chart

I would like to use special pie chart for my map, where the angle is not important, but area or radius of the arc carries information. I found, that this type of pie chart is calling Coxcomb/polar/rose (in Czech it is known as comparative) chart (see http://blogs.sas.com/content/jmp/files/2012/03/spending1.png or http://visual.ly/learn/coxcomb-chart), basicaly it is bar chart masked in pie :). Do you have any suggestions how to create this chart automaticaly or semiautomaticaly in gis (I prefer QGIS)?

Thanks for help,
Daniel